# Coin change with weights

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

This is a variation of the coin change problem. Where,

Given N coins with values : (5,10,20,50)

And weight having weights/probabilities W: (0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1)

What are the number of possible combinations, to make a sum : S = 100

whilst preserving the overall probability of each coin type. The same coin can be used multiple times. However, for example if 5 is used 10 times out of 100 coins to create the total S=100, then the probability is still 0.1. But if 5 is used 20 times in a solution to create S=100, then the prob(5) = 0.2, which is wrong.

Is there a similar variation to the coin-change problem ?

Is there a solution to this ? is it NP-hard ?

thanks

Comment: At first glance it seems there would be no solution.  If the coins satisfy the given weights, then the average value of a coin is $0.1\cdot 5 + 0.5\cdot 10 + 0.3\cdot 20+ 0.1\cdot 50=16.5$, which does not divide 100 evenly.

Comment: those weights were just examples. Assume arbitrary weights. the problem then is to determine if there is a solution or many solutions, and how to arrive at them.

Comment: In that case it seems like a simple question of whether or not the average value of your coins divides the desired sum.  If we have $n$ coins with face values $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and they occur with frequencies $f_1,\ldots,f_n$, then the average value is $v = f_1v_1+\cdots+f_nv_n$.  If $S/v$ is not an integer, there is no solution.  If $S/v$ is an integer and so are $Sf_i/v$ for each $i$, then letting the $i$-th coin appear $Sf_i/v$ times should do the trick.

Comment: okay I will try that. thank you